postfix virtual user email always redirected to root (was: how to reject non existent users from inside with mail command on smtp server)
After multiple tests I realize that what I explained below does not correctly describe the problem. The problem is broader than for internal mails on the server.
Basically, what I am trying to do is just add virtual users to my mail server which until now worked very well (in my opinion).
And I have the same problem with these virtual users as the one I explained below.
Everything works perfectly with real users (local), but any mail sent to a virtual user is systematically redirected to root.
Aug 26 16:50:03 _SMTPSERVER_._MYDOMAIN_ postfix/submissions/smtpd[22689]: connect from coffee._MYDOMAIN_[192.168.5.3]
Aug 26 16:50:03 _SMTPSERVER_._MYDOMAIN_ postfix/submissions/smtpd[22689]: Anonymous TLS connection established from coffee._MYDOMAIN_[192.168.5.3]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature ECDSA (prime256v1) server-digest SHA256
Aug 26 16:50:04 _SMTPSERVER_._MYDOMAIN_ postfix/submissions/smtpd[22689]: BC36E1C1651: client=coffee._MYDOMAIN_[192.168.5.3]
Aug 26 16:50:05 _SMTPSERVER_._MYDOMAIN_ postfix/cleanup[22694]: BC36E1C1651: message-id=<20240826205004.BC36E1C1651@mail._MYDOMAIN_>
Aug 26 16:50:05 _SMTPSERVER_._MYDOMAIN_ postfix/qmgr[20974]: BC36E1C1651: from=<chris@_MYDOMAIN_>, size=694, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 26 16:50:05 _SMTPSERVER_._MYDOMAIN_ postfix/submissions/smtpd[22689]: disconnect from coffee._MYDOMAIN_[192.168.5.3] helo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Aug 26 16:50:06 _SMTPSERVER_._MYDOMAIN_ postfix/local[22698]: BC36E1C1651: to=<root@_MYDOMAIN_>, orig_to=<virtualuser@_MYDOMAIN_>, relay=local, delay=3.4, delays=2.3/0.01/0/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/bin/procmail -Y -a $DOMAIN)
Aug 26 16:50:06 _SMTPSERVER_._MYDOMAIN_ postfix/qmgr[20974]: BC36E1C1651: removed

I no longer know what to do to find what causes this redirection in my settings. I feel like I have looked everywhere, without success.
My actual postfix conf:
# postconf -n
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases sqlite:/etc/postfix/sql-virtuals/sql-aliases.cf
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 3.8
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
delay_warning_time = 4
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps
local_transport = local
luser_relay = postmaster
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -Y -a $DOMAIN
mailbox_size_limit = 204800000
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
masquerade_domains = $mydomain $myorigin
message_size_limit = 102400000
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = pcre:/etc/postfix/mydestinations
mydomain = _MYDOMAIN_
myhostname = mail._MYDOMAIN_
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
procmail_destination_recipient_limit = 1
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
relocated_maps = sqlite:/etc/postfix/sql-virtuals/sql-relocated.cf
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_bcc_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib64/postfix/${mail_version}
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/saslpass
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtp_scache
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/bad_recipients permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unknown_recipient_domain reject_unauth_destination reject_unauth_pipelining reject_rbl_client noptr.spamrats.com reject_rbl_client spam.spamrats.com reject_rbl_client dyna.spamrats.com check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myorigin
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail._MYDOMAIN_/chain.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail._MYDOMAIN_/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail._MYDOMAIN_/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = sqlite:/etc/postfix/sql-virtuals/sql-aliases.cf regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_limit = $mailbox_size_limit
virtual_mailbox_maps = sqlite:/etc/postfix/sql-virtuals/sql-virtual-maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 600
virtual_transport = procmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000

# postmap -q virtualuser sqlite:/etc/postfix/sql-virtuals/sql-virtual-maps.cf
virtualuser/

# doveadm user virtualuser
field   value
uid     5000
gid     5000
home    /var/vmail/virtualuser
mail    maildir:/var/vmail/virtualuser/

# cat /etc/postfix/aliases
MAILER-DAEMON:  postmaster
postmaster:     root
bin:            root
daemon:         root
named:          root
nobody:         root
uucp:           root
www:            root
ftp-bugs:       root
postfix:        root
manager:        root
dumper:         root
operator:       root
abuse:          postmaster
decode:         root

Nothing abnormal in the sqlite aliases table and no alias to root destination.

Old question:
I have a mail server (postfix + dovecot) working fine for years.
Today, I realize that on the server itself, I can send email with the mail command to any user, even if non existing, and it is delivered to root.
$ hostname
vmserveur
$ echo "test" | mail -s "test" anyonenotexisting

Aug 25 15:28:07 vmserveur._MYDOMAIN_.fr postfix/pickup[9098]: 92F1A1C1319: uid=0 from=<root@vmserveur>
Aug 25 15:28:07 vmserveur._MYDOMAIN_.fr postfix/cleanup[9117]: 92F1A1C1319: message-id=<20240825192807.92F1A1C1319@mail._MYDOMAIN_.fr>
Aug 25 15:28:07 vmserveur._MYDOMAIN_.fr postfix/qmgr[9102]: 92F1A1C1319: from=<root@vmserveur>, size=322, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 25 15:28:08 vmserveur._MYDOMAIN_.fr postfix/local[9119]: 92F1A1C1319: to=<root@_MYDOMAIN_.fr>, orig_to=<anyonenotexisting>, relay=local, delay=1, delays=0.01/0/0/1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/bin/procmail -Y -a $DOMAIN)
Aug 25 15:28:08 vmserveur._MYDOMAIN_.fr postfix/qmgr[9102]: 92F1A1C1319: removed

All works well from other machines, and the same mail command is simply rejected by the smtp server.
$ hostname
coffee
$ echo "test" | mail -s "test" anyonenotexisting

Aug 25 15:41:56 vmserveur._MYDOMAIN_.fr postfix/submissions/smtpd[12165]: connect from coffee._MYDOMAIN_.fr[192.168.5.3]
Aug 25 15:41:56 vmserveur._MYDOMAIN_.fr postfix/submissions/smtpd[12165]: Anonymous TLS connection established from c
offee._MYDOMAIN_.fr[192.168.5.3]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits) key-exchange X25519 serve
r-signature ECDSA (prime256v1) server-digest SHA256
Aug 25 15:41:56 vmserveur._MYDOMAIN_.fr postfix/submissions/smtpd[12165]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from coffee._MYDOMAIN_.fr[192.168.5.3]: 550 5.1.1 <anyonenotexisting@_MYDOMAIN_.fr>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<root@_MYDOMAIN_.fr> to=<anyonenotexisting@_MYDOMAIN_.fr> proto=SMTP helo=<coffee>
Aug 25 15:41:56 vmserveur._MYDOMAIN_.fr postfix/submissions/smtpd[12165]: lost connection after RCPT from coffee._MYDOMAIN_.fr[192.168.5.3]
Aug 25 15:41:56 vmserveur._MYDOMAIN_.fr postfix/submissions/smtpd[12165]: disconnect from coffee._MYDOMAIN_.fr[192.168.5.3] helo=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 commands=2/3

Why ?
It's like I have a catchall somewhere that redirects everything except existing users.
There must be some configuration element that causes what I consider to be a defect, but I can't find what.
postconf -n:
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 3.8
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
delay_warning_time = 4
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
luser_relay = postmaster
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -Y -a $DOMAIN
mailbox_size_limit = 204800000
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
masquerade_domains = $mydomain $myorigin
message_size_limit = 102400000
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = pcre:/etc/postfix/mydestinations
mydomain = _MYDOMAIN_.fr
myhostname = mail._MYDOMAIN_.fr
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/21, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_bcc_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib64/postfix/${mail_version}
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/saslpass
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtp_scache
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/bad_recipients permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unknown_recipient_domain reject_unauth_destination reject_unauth_pipelining reject_rbl_client noptr.spamrats.com reject_rbl_client spam.spamrats.com reject_rbl_client dyna.spamrats.com check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myorigin
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail._MYDOMAIN_.fr/chain.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail._MYDOMAIN_.fr/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail._MYDOMAIN_.fr/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp

aliases:
MAILER-DAEMON:  postmaster
postmaster:     root
bin:            root
daemon:         root
named:          root
nobody:         root
uucp:           root
www:            root
ftp-bugs:       root
postfix:        root
manager:        root
dumper:         root
operator:       root
abuse:          postmaster
decode:         root
locamart:       root
christophe:     chris
apache:         root
plf:            chris
lantanas:       chris
belia:          chris,regine
marin:          chris
steluce:        chris
troisilets:     chris
locations:      chris
root:           novazur


Local mail, send with mailx or the mail command uses the sendmail - Postfix to Sendmail compatibility interface which  follows a different path and isn't sent over SMTP as far as I know.
That conforms to classic in-system sendmail delivery that honours /etc/aliases where most likely your system has a catch-all for root configured.  Remove that catch-all and mail to non-existent local user accounts should fail.
See the diagram in https://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html

Local submissions are received with the Postfix sendmail(1) compatibility command, and are queued in the maildrop queue by the privileged postdrop(1) command. This arrangement even works while the Postfix mail system is not running. The local pickup(8) server picks up local submissions, enforces some sanity checks to protect Postfix, and gives the sender, recipients and message content to the cleanup(8) server.


Question edited and I confirm that's postfix logs as indicated.
